# How to avoid that when applying a number formatting I supplant part of the last digits to 0?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

example:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}).format('54546464646464654650000000000000065464645')
"54.546.464.646.464.660.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000,00"
```

This is because when I format it, it places the last numbers in 0 and so you have no precision in the numbers that you show for example in amounts of money.

How could I solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may be entering a number too big. Perhaps a string solution could be used here:

```js
function format(val, decimals) {
  // You cannot use variables in regex syntax (/re/) so you must create a string
  // then create the regex using RegExp constructor
  const reStr = `(\\d{${decimals}})$`
  const decimalRe = new RegExp(reStr);
  
  return val
    .replace(decimalRe, '\,$1')             // Adds "," after last N numbers
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.'); // Adds "." every 3 numbers after ","
  
}

const res = format("54546464646464654650000000000000065464645", 2)

console.log(res)
```